# Load json section to Dictionary C# and preserver insertion order

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, appsettings, insertion-order

Json file entry looks like this: settings.json

```
{
"MyJson": {
    "Machine": "machine",
    "Date": "date",
    "Time": "time",
    "Milli": "milli"
}
}
```

And I am using below code to convert this json to dictionary in C#

```
 public static Dictionary<string,string> myDict{  get; private set; }

 var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true).Build();
        myDict = configuration.GetSection("MyJson").Get<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

This code is storing key based sorted entries in myDict. I want to maintain the insertion order in myDict. Is there are solution for this?

Comment: Dictionaries in C#/.Net do not maintain/guarantee any ordering of items. You absolutely can't achieve anything like what you are looking for using Dictionary. Also JSON generally generated from objects and order of fields there is usually not related to the serialization order... Please clarify what you want to achieve and what you are ok to give up (looks like at least you have to give up on using `Dictionary`) - [edit] the post with those clarifications.

Comment: Use an [Ordered Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-7.0).

Comment: With Ordered Dictionary, its not converting json to the dictionary. 
```
myDict= configuration.GetSection("MyJson").Get<OrderedDictionary>();```

Comment: @JaspreetKaurBanwait There is no practical use to mantain the order. If you need it for some reason add to each item  an order number

Answer (score -2):

There is no any practical use in order maintaining. If you need it for some weird reason, add to each item an order number like this, for example

```
"MyJson": {
    "10 Machine": "machine",
    "20 Date": "date",
    "25 Time": "time",
    "30 Milli": "milli"
}

Dictionary<string,string> myDict = configuration.GetSection("MyJson")
                          .Get<Dictionary<string,string>>()
                          .ToDictionary(x => x.Key.Substring(3), x => x.Value);
```

output

```
{
"MyJson": {
    "Machine": "machine",
    "Date": "date",
    "Time": "time",
    "Milli": "milli"
}
```

another more complicated way is to load config file directly from disk and parse it

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); 

string json = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, "settings.json"));

Dictionary<string,string> myDict = JObject.Parse(json)["MyJson"]
                                  .ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

Comment: Adding numbers in key solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

```
public static LinkedDictionary<string, string> myDict { get; private set; }
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true).Build();

myDict = configuration.GetSection("MyJson").Get<LinkedDictionary<string,string();
```

Comment: Explain why this works in the way that the OP wants.

Comment: In C#, the Dictionary<TKey, TValue> class does not guarantee the preservation of insertion order. If you want to maintain the insertion order of the JSON properties, you can use the LinkedDictionary<TKey, TValue> class from the System.Collections.Specialized namespace.

Comment: Put that in your answer, please.

Comment: Along with link to the documentation (ideally on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized?view=net-7.0 )

Comment: I don't see LinkedDictionary in below documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized?view=net-7.0

Comment: @YusufKaraman there is no System.Collections.Specialized.LinkedDictionary

Comment: Were you thinking about `ListDictionary`? Because that isn't generic, and it also doesn't guarantee order.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh sorry, i am checking my answers  and this answers is wrong, sorry. In C#, the Dictionary<TKey, TValue> class does not guarantee the preservation of insertion order. However, starting from .NET Framework 4.0, you can use the OrderedDictionary class from the System.Collections.Specialized namespace to maintain the insertion order of elements.

Comment: Here's an updated version of the code to achieve this:                                                `public static OrderedDictionary myDict { get; private set; }

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true).Build();
var section = configuration.GetSection("MyJson");

myDict = new OrderedDictionary();
foreach (var item in section.GetChildren())
{
    myDict.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
}`